# How massive is the most massive known structure -- the Great Attractor -- and how much mass will it get?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, mass

So I [asked a question about dark flow](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310635/do-dark-flow-findings-suggest-were-moving-towards-distant-gravitational-anomaly) in which I inquired whether we were moving towards the "great attractor" and asking if there was visualizations of what that meant.  While I received no answer, turns out while poking around on the internet I found that ironically [a major new study](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41550-016-0036) had been published around the same time, which had [precisely what I was looking for](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/332284/143257).

It turns out yes we are moving towards the Shapely attractor, as is everything else in our neighborhood...

[image: Shapely Attractor]

My new question (with that settled) is that per the current understanding how dense is this "overdense" region estimated to be? (Or put slightly differently `"How much mass is estimated to be concentrated in the densest region of the great attractor?"`)

Secondly, assuming that our local group and the surrounding matter that appears on course to merge with the Shapely Attractor stays the course, and all that combined mass collapses into an ultramassive black hole or comparable ultra-massive object, how much mass can that monstrous singularity be estimated to have in the end?

I think these questions bear some intrigue in a "most massive object in the known universe" sense.  Perhaps it is somewhere in the study text, but I didn't see that exact figure.

Comment: You do know that [the dark flow is highly controversial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_flow#Criticisms), and there is no consensus even on its existence, let alone on the kind of specifics you are asking about?

Comment: Oh certainly.  Few things are known absolutely and many are best described as "controversial narrow majorities among theorists"... dark flow falling into that binning.  I'm referring to this study http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/810/2/143/ and the one linked above.  They have yet to be decisively refuted, and from a layman's view it seems compelling that they use they showcases evidence from one of the strongest published refutations (the 2013 WMAP results) arguing that it actually buttresses their claims.  Right or wrong, that seems like a bold move.

Comment: I'm a Ph.D. in an engineering discipline involving physics, but no physicist... what I'm asking is simply a napkin math estimate of the current mass, which I believe should be possible to plausibly estimate based on the data provided in the latest Jan. '17 Nature Astronomy study.  I'd be uncomfortable making that estimate myself, though, hence the question to my physics friends.   I do understand your criticism.  If you want to edit to insert some disclaimer warning on the controversy, please by all means do.  But I think the question is feasible to answer and compelling, controversy aside.